# Besides jointly normal random variable, what other distribution satisfies uncorrelated if and only if independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, independence

It is well known that for a jointly normally distributed random variables $(X_1,...,X_n)^T,$ they are uncorrelated if and only if independent.

It is also well-known that for any random variable, independent implies uncorrelated but not the converse.

Here comes my question:

> Question: Besides jointly normal random variable, what other distribution satisfies uncorrelated if and only if independent?

Comment: You can replace the $\exp(-x^2)$ by another function in the multivariate normal distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution

Comment: The question is not about individual distributions but of families of multivariate distributions. A problem is that there are not well known examples. When would you say that $X^n=(X_1,\cdots X_n)$ is a multivariate (say) Poisson? When each $X_1$ is marginally Poisson ? But that doesn't agree with the definition of a multivariate normal. 
A quick (but not very interesting) answer would be: any familiy of multivariate distributions that is fully characterized by its mean and covariance qualifies. And the only well-known such multivariate distributions are the normal and (less so) the Bernoulli

Answer (score 5):

As a trivial example:

Let $X,Y$ be two uncorrelated coin flips (i.e. each are $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $0$ with probability $1/2$ and $E(XY)=1/4$).

Then \begin{align*}\frac14 &=E(XY)\\&=1\cdot P(X=1,Y=1)+0\cdot P(X=1,Y=0)+0\cdot P(X=0,Y=1)+0\cdot P(X=0,y=0)\\&=P(X=1,Y=1)\end{align*}

Or $P(X=1,Y=1)=1/4=P(X=1)P(Y=1)$.

Then by law of total probability $P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=1)=1/2$ so $P(X=1,Y=0)=1/4=P(X=1)P(Y=0)$.

The rest follow.

Comment: Just wanna point out that the coins do not have to be fair. For any two possibly different, possibly unfair coins, with $P(H) = p_1, p_2$ respectively, non-correlation implies independence via basically the same arithmetic proof.

Comment: @antkam Of course, thanks for the input. I was just keeping things simple.

Comment: This does not work for more than two. For example, let $X_1,X_2 \sim \text{i.i.d.}$ and equal to $0$ or $1$ each with probability $1/2,$ and let $X_3$ be the mod-$2$ sum of $X_1$ and $X_2.$ Then $X_1,X_2$ are independent, $X_1,X_3$ are independent, and $X_2,X_3$ are independent, but $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are not independent.

Answer (score 3):

Here we're talking about families of distributions rather than about individual distributions. If I specify just one distribution for a tuple $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ of random variables and it happens that they are independent and have finite variances, then I can say they're independent if and only if they're uncorrelated, and if it happens that they have all non-zero covariences, then I can also say they're independent if and only if they're uncorrelated. So **any** distribution matching either of these two descriptions is an example of the kind requested, but an uninteresting example.

Here's just one example that's somewhat more interesting. Suppose you have a Poisson process on a measure space (which, as often happens, could for example be the Euclidean plane with Lebesgue measure). Let $X_A$ be the number of "arrivals" within the measurable set $A,$ so that $X_A\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(m(A)),$ where $m(A)$ is the measure of $A.$ (In the plane example, one would usually just say that $m(A)$ is the area of the region $A$ in the plane.)

Then $X_{A_1}, \ldots, X_{A_n}$ are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated, and also if and only if $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are pairwise disjoint.

One might say this is a family of distributions parametrized by the tuple $(A_1,\ldots,A_n),$ but the joint distribution depends on the choice of that tuple only through the measures of their intersections, so the latter should probably be taken to be the parameter space.